# Kill pid Jenkinsfile Jenkins

Tags: frameworks, jenkins-pipeline, pid, kill, playback

I have a jenkinsfile from which I am autodeploying a play framework application. To kill the current pid on the server I use the following command:

```
sudo kill $(cat /var/www/myProject/PLAY.pid)
```

I've tried escaping the dollar sign as suggested without success. The Jenkins log returns

Kill: command not found

Is this a syntactical error or is there a problem invoking 'kill' from Jenkins on ubuntu 18.04?...

I can't see any documentation on the Play Framework website for starting and stopping packaged binaries using an automated shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your are trying to do in Jenkins pipelines you have to escape $ characters so been said that you have to do:

```
sh "sudo kill \$(cat /var/www/myProject/PLAY.pid)"
```

Please, notice the "\$".

Comment: Thanks for your response Daniel. Apologies, I had already tried this resolution and put it down to being a syntax error as I was still getting errors in the Jenkins log. I've edited the original post.